# A result on the index related to two subgroups of a group $G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$, show that $[H\vee K:H]\geq [K:H\cap K]$.

I tried using Lagrange's Theorem to prove this one, but to no avail I couldn't get the desired proof. Can anyone provide hints on how to have a kickstart in writing a proof for this? Just hints and key pointers. I still want to provide proof for this on my own. Thank you.

Comment: It's the join, Sir @ArturoMagidin. Let me edit the question.

Comment: In that case, look for a proof that $|HK||H\cap K| = |H||K|$ and then use the fact that $HK\subseteq \langle H,K\rangle$.

Comment: Hello Sir @ArturoMagidin, why exactly is $HK\subseteq \left<H,K\right>$ and not the other way around?

Comment: $HK=\{hk\mid h\in H, k\in K\}$. Surely any subgroup that contains both $H$ and $K$ must contain all products of that form.

Comment: Is $\left<H,K\right>$ the same as $H\vee K$?

Comment: Yes. The notation $\langle X\rangle$ stands for “subgroup generated by $X$”, and more generally for subsets, not necessarily subgroups, $A$, $B$, etc., $\langle A,B,\ldots,\rangle$ is the smallest subgroup that contains $A$, $B$, etc.

Comment: So the notation is more general, because it does not require $A$ and $B$ to be subgroups, just subsets; whereas $A\vee B$ requires $A$ and $B$ to be subgroups.

Answer (score 1):

I denote the set of lateral classes of $B$ in $A$ as $A/B$. Recall that in general $[A:B] = | A/B |$.

Take representatives $ \{x_i\}_{i \in I} $ for the lateral classes of $H\cap K$ in $K$, so that $K/H \cap K = \{ x_i H \cap K\}_{i \in I}$. Note that $x_i \in K$.

Try to show that the classes $x_i H \in H \vee K / H$ are still distinct, so that we have an injective map $ K/ H \cap K \to H \vee K / H$.

Comment: Ugh; don't use $\cup$ for the join....

Comment: Seems like it was the OP notation... had to get copromised, sir

Comment: And he fixed it...

Comment: I put some points to be completed at the end...

Comment: Also, he can always stop reading when he wants. Help we give on mathstackexchange is free and any contribute should be welcomed ;)

Comment: I'm not getting what's going on here. Do you want to rap battle? XD

Comment: By the way, I cut off the last paragraph